# Reorder multiple ranges in Google Sheets with apps script?

Tags: google-sheets

Recently I got automatic reorder code working for range DY29:EA43 (thanks to you), but I want also automatically reorder additional multiple ranges but I can't figure it out how I can run multiple functions in Apps Script?

Ranges I want to automatic reorder in addition:

- Range DY47:EA60 by percentage in column EA (EA47:EA60).
- Range DY65:EA77 by value in column EA (EA65:EA77).
- Range DY82:EA95 by percentage in column EA (EA82:EA95).
- Range DY99:EA113 by percentage in column EA (EA99:EA113).

Code I have now:

```js
function myFunction(){
  sample();
}

function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const a1Notations = ["B3:J7", "B11:J15", "B19:J23", "B27:J31", "B35:J39", "B43:J47", "B51:J55", "B59:J63"];
  const ranges = sheet.getRangeList(a1Notations).getRanges();
  const formatRanges = a1Notations.map(r => r.replace(/^./, "J"));
  sheet.getRangeList(formatRanges).setNumberFormat("0");
  ranges.forEach(r => r.sort({ column: r.getLastColumn(), ascending: false }));
  sheet.getRangeList(formatRanges).setNumberFormat("@");
}

function sample() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("EA29:EA43");
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  const mFormulas = formulas.map(([ea]) => [ea.replace(/=SUM\(([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)\+([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)\)/i, "=SUM($$$1$$$2+$$$3$$$4)")]);
  if (JSON.stringify(formulas) != JSON.stringify(mFormulas)) range.setFormulas(mFormulas);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sheet.getRange("DY29:EA43").sort({ column: 131, ascending: false });
}
```

Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZyUuDAp85Vr76NMmqQXuLqTUMMuHP6sQu2gvQREhDU/edit#gid=446993580

Answer (score 0):

### #1

Try

```
function reOrder() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ["DY47:EA60", "DY65:EA77", "DY82:EA95", "DY99:EA113"].forEach(rng => {
    let values = sheet.getRange(rng).getValues()
    values = values.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a[2] - b[2];
    });
    sheet.getRange(rng).setValues(values)
  })
}
```

### #2

or to keep formulas

```
function reOrder() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ["DY47:EA60", "DY65:EA77", "DY82:EA95", "DY99:EA113"].forEach(rng => {
    sheet.getRange(rng).sort([{ column: 131, ascending: true }]);
  })
}
```

### #3

last solution, according to the complixity of your spreadsheet, in EC47

```
=sort(arrayformula({DY47:DZ60,(EA47:EA60)*1}),3,1)
```

same for other ranges

you will need to show all rows

Comment: Multiple values in the table become zero after running this function...
Or am I doing something wrong? :)

Comment: Probably due to complex formulas that I hadn't paid attention to at first. I will study in depth, while also waiting for another answer... Sorry!

Comment: I was wondering if it wasn't easier to duplicate the tables and reorganize them by query formulas for example, or to sort (native function).

Comment: How can I do that?
Sorry, I'm complete rookie in Google Sheets. :)

Comment: See solution #3